# force using document probertiy subject on save

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need a word document to use the document property subject as sugested filename when saving.
It is default for new document, but not for old ones already saved.

So I do

```
ActiveDocument.saved = False
```

to reset the behavior, but it doesn't work. subject is not proposed.

Why is that?

BR Kresten

Comment: When saving a new document Word uses either the Title property or, if Title hasn't been set, the first line of text in the document. Once a file has been saved Word will only use the existing file name. To force the use of Subject as the file name you need to write some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Document.Saved` property is used in VBA to indicate whether a document contains unsaved changes. Setting `ActiveDocument.Saved = False` is a valid way of prompting a document to be saved, though IIRC it can be unreliable.

However, setting it will only result in the File Save As dialog being shown if the document has been newly created and is being saved for the very first time. At any other time it will simply result in the document being saved with the existing path and filename, and the user getting the prompt to save if they attempt to close it.

You could write code for the Save commands, though this won't catch the save that occurs when the user closes the document.

```
Sub FileSaveAs()
   Dim dlgFileSave As Dialog
   Set dlgFileSave = Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
   With dlgFileSave
      .Name = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertySubject)
      .Show
   End With
End Sub

Sub FileSave()
   FileSaveAs
End Sub
```

Or you could write an application level event handler that will intercept the Save event, something like below, which will catch any Save. You can find further information on doing this at the [Word MVP site](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/InterceptSavePrint.htm).

```
Private Sub oApp_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, _
  SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
   Dim dlgFileSave As Dialog
   Set dlgFileSave = Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
   With dlgFileSave
      .Name = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertySubject)
      .Show
   End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveDocument.Saved = True` is used in VBA to suppress the Word message **Save your changes to this file?** when closing a temporary document. Setting it to false will have no effect on an already-saved file.

This code will run each time you use the **File>Save As** command. Change the name and add the macro to the QAT if you don't want it to work on every Word file:

```
Sub FileSaveAs()
  Dim oFileSaveDlg
  Set oFileSaveDlg = Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
  With oFileSaveDlg
    .Name = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertySubject)
    .Show
  End With
End Sub
```